# Show that $l^p \subseteq l^q$ for $1 \leq p < q < \infty$

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces

$$l^p = \{ (a_k)_{k \geq 1} : \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^p < \infty \}$$

Since it is said $l^p \subseteq l^q$, I would have thought we have to show $$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^q \geq \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^p$$ but I heard we have to show it for $\leq$

If $l^p \subseteq l^q$, then $l^p$ is contained in $l^q$ so talking informally, $l^p$ should be "smaller" than $l^q$ so that is why I thought we have to show the above inequality...

---

OK so it is said 
to prove that $ℓ^p⊆ℓ^q$
 it means to show that if $x=(a_k)∈ℓ^p
$

i.e. the condition that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^p$$
converges holds, then $x∈ℓ^q$

i.e. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^q$$
 converges. This implication does not involve any inequalities.

So can we say:

Let $A_k=|a_k|^p$ and since $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^p$$
converges, then the ratio test would tell us that $$\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{A_{k+1}}{A_k}=\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|a_{k+1}|^p}{|a_k|^p}=\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \bigg( \frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|} \bigg)^p = \bigg( \lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|} \bigg)^p <1$$ so we have $$\bigg( \lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|} \bigg)^p<1 \iff \bigg( \bigg( \lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|} \bigg)^p \bigg) ^{q/p}<1 \iff \bigg( \lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|} \bigg)^q <1$$ which means it converges for $q$?

Comment: The ratio test can also yield $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{A_{k + 1}}{A_k}=1$. I've already written a correct proof in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no general inequality which holds:
The sequences $$a_0 = 2, a_k = 0, k > 0$$ and $$b_0 = \frac{1}{2}, b_k = 0,k > 0$$ should show that (take i.e. $p = 1, q = 2$).

To prove $l^p \subseteq l^q$, you have to take a sequence $(a_k) \in l^p$ and show that it is in $l^q$. First, observe that we can assume without loss of generality that $a_k < 1$ (otherwise we just cut off the first finitely many terms). Then we have $a_k^p > a_k^q$ and the claim follows.

Comment: to be honest, with the definition of $l^p$, I can barely see how the p and q are contributed because the sequences are just bounded in their sum. I don't really understand what you did aswell... are you sure this cannot be proved in general terms? It would have said in the question to give a specific eg otherwise...

Comment: That both inequalities don't hold follows by the counterexamples I've given in the answer.

Moreover: If $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \lvert a_k \rvert^p$ converges, then $a_k$ is a nullsequence (early analysis course). That's all you need.

Comment: what if p were to be swapped with q? would that be true? Maybe it is a typo?

Comment: For both cases I've given a counterexample:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \lvert a_k \rvert^1 = 2 < \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \lvert a_k \rvert^2 = 4$$
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \lvert b_k \rvert^1 = \frac{1}{2} > \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \lvert b_k \rvert^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: oh this question doesn't seem to make any sense at all then............

Comment: OK so it is said 
to prove that $ℓ^p⊆ℓ^q$
 it means to show that if $x=(a_k)∈ℓ^p
$

 i.e. the condition that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^p$$
converges holds, then $x∈ℓ^q$

i.e. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^q$$
 converges. This implication does not involve any inequalities.

Comment: Please help! ${}$ ${}$