# Show $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^q$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $1 \leq p < q < \infty$. Show that if $x=(a_k)∈ℓ^p$

i.e. the condition that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^p$$
converges holds, then $x∈ℓ^q$

i.e. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^q$$
 converges.

I did try to use the ratio test but I don't think it will work because of the power on the terms in the series.

Comment: What do $p$ and $q$ have to do with each other?

Comment: sorry fixed now

Comment: Why the deliberate self-duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1628081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^p < \infty,$ $|a_n|^p \to 0.$ Thus there exists $N$ such that $|a_n|^p< 1$ for $n\ge N.$ For such $n$ we can say that, since $q/p > 1,$

$$|a_n|^q = (|a_n|^p)^{q/p}\le |a_n|^p.$$

Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^q$ converges by the comparison test.